# Acessar minha aplicação sem o número da versão

Tags: jsf, maven, url, wildfly

Minha aplicação JSF é executada no wildfly. Porém quando eu levanto o servidor, para acessar a aplicação devo usar: http://localhost:8180/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/inicio.jsf. 
Resumindo: Quero tirar o **-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT** e só usar http://localhost:8180/app/inicio.jsf.

Não sei se isso é configurado no pom, mas o mesmo está assim:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>pokemax</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Na pasta target do projeto está correto, porém é no wildfly que aparece com o snapshot, mesmo depois da sua sugestão continua a mesma coisa.

Comment: @renan não é mudar o nome do projeto, mas é que o wildfly quando vai fazer o deploy, reconhece a app com o número da versão na frente...e eu quero que ele reconheça só com o nome da app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa o [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly-mojo.html):

```
<configuration>
  <finalName>app</finalName>
  <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
</configuration>
```

Coloca isso no teu pom que quando for gerar o war vai gerar com o nome que você definir no finalName.

Comment: Só com o  <finalName> já resolveu, mesmo assim obrigado.